# Insertion Sort with Strings Difficulties

Tags: java, string, for-loop, insertion-sort

Attempting to write an insertion sort to sort an array of strings..

```
public static void insertionSort(String[] list) 
{
    for (int i = 1; i <list.length; i++)
    {
        String currentElement = list[i];
        int k;
        for (k=i-1; k >= 0 && list[k] > currentElement; k--) //error here
        {
            list[k+1]=list[k];
        }
        list[k+1] = currentElement;
    }
}
```

I'm getting the error The operator > is undefined for the argument type, but I thought I had learned in class that you could compare strings with >, <, etc? How would I go about fixing this problem?

Comment: Maybe you had learned that in a VB programming class, but definitely not Java (or most other languages for that matter).

Answer (score 4):

You cannot compare objects, including `String`s, with comparison operators such as `>`.  You must call a method that does the comparison.  `String` is [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)`<String>`, so replace

```
list[k] > currentElement
```

with

```
list[k].compareTo(currentElement) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

No. You cannot compare any Object including String with the greater or smaller operators.

You can compare strings using a collation, which is language-specific. If you want to compare strings based on the Unicode values of their characters, you can use the `compareTo(String)` method of the String class. See the Java documentation for the String class.